# JQuery OnClick for Repeating Element in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP .NET MVC view that has the following:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item)
    }
```

Inside my DisplayTemplate I have basically the following:

```
 <a>Hello @Model.Name</a>

 <script>
       $(???).click(function() {...});
 </script>
```

I want to use jquery to add a click handler inside my DisplayTemplate (not in the main view).

I can't assign a unique id to the anchor in my DisplayTemplate because it's repeated. How can I target my anchor in jquery so that I can add the click handler? I've considered doing something like creating a unique guid for each DisplayTemplate instance and setting that as the id, but it seems terribly hacky.

Comment: Use a CSS class like `class="item"`, and `$('.item')`? In the event handler, `this` will refer to only the item that was clicked, not to the original selector. I'm not sure what you're trying to ultimately accomplish though, whether you're trying to *attach* a click handler to all of the items or only one of them.

Comment: your jquery should go in your main view. the class assignment in the display template

Comment: I'm trying to attach a click handler for all, but each click handler has some different logic based on the model. Using a class will result in multiple elements being returned by the selector, which won't work for my purposes (because the same event will be attached twice).

Comment: If you need different behaviour for each link then obviously each needs to be identifiable in some manner, whether that be by unique ids with separate click handlers, or a common class but some `data-` attribute(s) with additional information where the click handler would have conditional logic based on the value of the `data-` attribute(s).

Comment: Give examples of different logic you would use with different click events. The more examples and more detailed, the easier to help...

Comment: Sorry, my comment was confusing and not really accurate... What I meant to say was that each caller has some different logic for populating the data in the model. My situation is more along the lines of: many different views may want to display this DisplayTemplate...some in a loop, some for just one. Accordingly, I don't want to repeat the javascript in each place where this DisplayTemplate gets used (it should be self contained).